# Two-Way binding in an Aurelia Custom Attribute

Tags: javascript, aurelia

> **UPDATE:**  It looks like this is a known bug: **https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/253**
>   I am leaving it here for reference / searchability purposes.

## The Code:

**input-mask.ts**  (Full code can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/e532610df4bff3211eb1))

```
@customAttribute('input-mask')
@inject(Element)
export class InputMaskCustomAttribute {

    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay,
                changeHandler: 'onUnmaskedValueChanged'  })
    unmaskedValue: any;

    onUnmaskedValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('unmaskedValue updated from inside the custom attribute');
    }

    @bindable
    mask: string;

    attached() {

          this.eventTarget.on('focusout', (e: any) => {
             this.unmaskedValue = (<any>$(this.element)).cleanVal()
             this.fireEvent(e.target, 'input');
          });
    }

  // Code for constructor, fireEvent and to setup the mask...
}
```

**carrier.html**

```
<input input-mask="mask.bind: carrier.airbillMask; unmasked-value.bind: airbill" 
       value.bind="formattedAirbill"/>
```

> **UPDATE:** To work around this bug, change to `unmasked-value.two-way` and the binding will work.

**carrier.ts**

```
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay})
carrier: EntityInterfaces.ICarrier;

@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay })
formattedAirbill: string;

@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay, changeHandler: 'onAirbillChanged' })
airbill: string;

onAirbillChanged() {
    console.log('Airbill was set!');
}
```

## The Problem:

The data seems to flow into the `@bindable` variable just fine.  As the mask changes, the value in the custom attribute is changed.

But it does not seem to flow out if changes are made inside the custom-attribute.

*Example Scenario:* 
After I edit the value in the input box, and exit the input, the `focusout` event fires and the console statement that indicates that the unmasked Value was updated from inside the custom attribute prints:

> unmaskedValue updated from inside the custom attribute

But (when the input looses focus) the console statement saying that the `airbill` on the carrier.ts file was updated does not fire when I exit the input box:

> This does not fire:
>   console.log('Airbill was set!');

This seems to show to me that the binding is not really two-way.

## The Question:

**How can I make this binding two-way?  So that when I update `unmaskedValue` inside the custom-attribute it will update the bound value in the view model?**

Note: As a workaround, I was able change `unmasked-value.bind` to be a method call (`on-unmasked-value-changed.call="onUnmaskedValueChanged($event)`) and update the value in that method.  So I don't NEED this to work.  But I would like to know if it is possible for future use.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/253

Comment: Changing the binding to `.two-way` (instead of just `.bind`) in the HTML works around this issue.

Comment: Looks like this issue was closed, can you use it the way you wanted to now, without the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This known bug have been fixed and closed  on Mar 15, 2016
https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/253#issuecomment-189394955

Answer (score -1):

Try to initialize the variable unmaskedValue with default value. Try null, undefined, '' and so on. I have done this before but I don`t remember in which version (certainly it was beta)