# jQuery plugin not working with Aurelia in Firefox only

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, aurelia, jspm

I've started an Aurelia project and I've opted to use [this plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) to enable input masking for phone numbers using an implementation similar to that seen in [this post](https://github.com/aurelia/documentation/issues/193).

It works fine in Chrome and Safari - however, it just plain doesn't work in Firefox. No errors or other useful information. The examples on the above-linked demo page work just fine, however, so I'm sure it must be something with my implementation:

**JS:**

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ValidationController, ValidationRules, validateTrigger} from 'aurelia-validation';
import 'igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin'

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))

export class MyForm {
  async activate(params, routeConfig) {
    // do stuff if there are route parameters
  }

  bind() {
    $('#PhoneNumber').mask('(000) 000-0000');
  }

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
  }

  submit() {
    this.controller.validate()
      .then(errors => {
        if (errors.length === 0) {
          // do a thing
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
      });
  }
}

ValidationRules
  .ensure('phoneNumber').displayName('Phone number')
  .minLength(10).withMessage('Phone number must be at least 10 characters')
  .maxLength(14).withMessage('Phone number is too long')
  .matches(/[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/).withMessage('Please provide a valid phone number')
  .on(MyForm);
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" id="PhoneNumber" type="tel" minlength="10" maxlength="14" pattern="[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" value.bind="phoneNumber & validate" required="required">
```

I've tried removing the pattern attribute and changing it to regular text input, to no avail. I'm really scratching my head on this one. Any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with Jan - we never did get it to work in Firefox the way the original question is coded.

We did end up replacing it with jquery.inputmask because we ran into compatibility issues with jquery.mask('igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin').

Here is the glue that made it work (based on [Two-Way binding in an Aurelia Custom Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658280/two-way-binding-in-an-aurelia-custom-attribute)):

**input-mask.js**

```
import {inject, customAttribute, bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'jquery.inputmask';
import 'jquery.inputmask.numeric';

@customAttribute('input-mask')
@inject(Element)
export class InputMaskCustomAttribute {

  @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) unmaskedValue;

  @bindable maskOptions;

  element;

  isValidInputElement;
  // The maskedinput jquery pluggin does not allow the events that aurelia needs
  // for binding to get through.  So we will manually put them through.
  // This is the list of events we are going to look for.  "focusout" allows for the value
  // to be correct intime for "onblur".
  aureliaBindEvents = 'focusout';
  eventTarget = undefined;

  constructor(element) {
    if (element instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      this.element = element;
      this.isValidInputElement = true;
      this.eventTarget = $(this.element);
    } else {
      this.isValidInputElement = false;
    }
  }

  bind() {
    this.element.value = this.unmaskedValue;
  }

  attached() {
    this.setupMask();
  }

  detached() {
    this.tearDownMask();
  }

  maskOptionsChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    this.tearDownMask();
    this.setupMask();
  }

  setupMask(mask) {
    if (this.isValidInputElement && this.maskOptions) {
      this.eventTarget.inputmask(this.maskOptions);
      this.eventTarget.on(this.aureliaBindEvents, (e) => {
        this.unmaskedValue = this.eventTarget.inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
        this.fireEvent(e.target, 'input');
      });
    }
  }

  tearDownMask() {
    if (this.isValidInputElement) {
      if (this.eventTarget) {
        this.eventTarget.off(this.aureliaBindEvents);
        this.eventTarget.inputmask('remove');
      }
    }
  }

  createEvent(name: string) {
    let event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    return event;
  }

  fireEvent(element: HTMLElement, name: string) {
    var event = this.createEvent(name);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

}
```

**widget.html**

```
<require from="input-mask"></require>
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="12" 
  input-mask="mask-options.bind: {alias: 'currency', rightAlign: false, allowMinus:false, allowPlus: false}; unmasked-value.bind: target['monthly-payment'] & validate" />
```

Comment: I don't get it. If I copy your code, then when I hover (or focus) over the input element, word currency appears, but the input is not editable, meaning that it does not respond to entering any value.

Comment: I think this because you did pull in  jquery.inputmask.numeric.js in your dependency manager.
Here is how I did it using JSPM (in the 'map' key within config.js):
`"jquery.inputmask": "npm:jquery.inputmask@3.3.3",
 "jquery.inputmask.numeric": "npm:jquery.inputmask@3.3.3/dist/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js",`

Comment: I actually f*cked up something else... Thanks for help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery commands on `attached()` event (after html-rendering), not on `bind()`. Try that:

```
attached() {
  $('#PhoneNumber').mask('(000) 000-0000');
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work in Firefox (Chrome is fine, though). Any other ideas?

Comment: Press "CTRL+SHIFT+J" in firefox to see all error logs in javascript console for more info about problem. Can you see any suspect there?

Comment: Standard Aurelia dev debugging statements plus the output of  console.log I put in the attached method to make sure it fired - no errors. Debug output seems to be the same between Chrome and FF too, so nothing seems to be loaded differently.